# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed in Python in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running a simple Py script but failed to verify SSL certificate though I set verify = False
can anyone suggest any changes to the script ?

Script

```
import json
import requests
r = requests.get('https://splunk.prod.internal.forwarders.tools.cso-hp.com:8088/services/collector' ,verify = False)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: [ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='splunk.prod.internal.forwarders.tools.cso-hp.com', port=8088): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/collector (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f931fdaaa00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: If you change the URL to something else (eg google.com), does it still give an error? This will help determine whether the problem is with the remote site, or something regarding Lambda. Also, is the AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, it does not receive Internet access unless you have a NAT Gateway. Please edit your question to provide additional information about your Lambda configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided is `Name or service not known` which means that most likely the lambda function can't resolve the provided DNS record. This looks like a private DNS record, so put your function in VPC if this record is created via a private hosted zone or you're using a custom nameserver